# Postman returning an empty response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman, backend

I am working on connecting the backend of my app to mongodb and when I test with postman, it returns an empty body - I have no idea what is going on. The database is successfully connected.

I have coded a model with 5 entries as seen below and also have the app.js file (also below). I have put the route in the app.js file in order to make it more clear. I have double checked and I have exported everything but I have no idea what is going wrong. I have coded backend of other react apps in the same way, and the postman has always worked perfectly.

Also, my postman settings has "Content-Type" set to application/json and everything else is unchecked.

app.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const router = require('express').Router();
const DiaryEntry = require('./models/diaryEntry')
require('dotenv').config()

//App
const app = express()

//database
mongoose.connect(process.env.ATLAS_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
}).then(() => console.log("Database Connected"))



//middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

router.route("/").get((req, res) => {
  DiaryEntry.find()
    .then(diaryEntries => res.json(diaryEntries))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
  });



const port = process.env.PORT || 5000 //default PORT

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

Schema (Model):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const diaryEntrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  mood: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: false
  },
  entry1: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    trim: true
  },
  entry2: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    trim: true
  },
  entry3: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    trim: true
  }
}, {timestamps: true}
);

const DiaryEntry = mongoose.model('DiaryEntry', diaryEntrySchema);

module.exports = DiaryEntry;
```

And finally, the post request to json (get request doesnt work either):

```
{
    "mood": 8,
    "entry1": "hey",
    "entry2": "test",
    "entry3": "whats up"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to mongoose [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) for `.find() takes in one arg and it can be an empty obj to find all the entries in the collection.

for example:

```
MyModel.find({}).then(data => do something with data);
```

Comment: The response is still empty

Comment: What are the errors you are seeing in your console, if any ?

Answer (score 0):

use this

`DiaryEntry.find().exec() .then(diaryEntries => res.json(diaryEntries)) .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err)); });`

after find and findOne method in mongoose you should use `exec()`

Comment: It is still returning a blank response. I am super confused.

Comment: Is there any data in your collection? Did you insert any data? please change your response to this code `res.json({ success: true, diaryEntries })`. then tell me what is the value of `diaryEntries`

Comment: Yes, I manually put in data to the MongoDB cluster. I changed the code, but it is still giving me a blank response. It says "Status: 400 Bad Request" and that my syntax is bad but I have no idea how or why.

Comment: What is the value of 'err' in catch?

Comment: You shoud use json format in res.json(). You can not use string. If you want to pass string you should use res.send("Error: " + err)